# ADFS server error 403 - Forbidden: Access is Denied

Tags: 2013, authentication, adfs, ntlm

Currently trying to copy a working farm that uses ADFS to authenticate users. My SharePoint farm authenticates users perfectly using NTLM. I followed the steps provided by Microsoft to set up an ADFS server and attempted to copy the settings from the working farm. When I set the authentication mode to the Trusted Identity Provider, a user who tries to reach SharePoint is routed to the ADFS server, where they receive the 403 error.

Enabled detail reporting. The specific error I am getting is: HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden
The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.

Answer (score -1):

looks like issue with SSL certificate.

- please make sure you bind the SSL certificate with the web application in IIS.ADFS need a SSL certificate as one of the requirements
- also make sure you properly import the ADFS sts and root certificate while configuring on Devon farm
- it is not simple like copy the things, you need relying party package, then configuration at sharepoint side

Comment: The SSL certificate is binded to the IIS ADFS web app. Is it ok if the cert is a wildcard certificate?

Comment: Is it a problem if we are using a wildcard cert for the ADFS service? The certificates were imported properly, but does it matter which certificate store is used? To clarify, we are trying to use this with a smartcard and the browser is not even prompting for authentication.

Comment: i think wildcard certs is not a problem. as long as they are properly configured. can you click on the lock sign in the browser and try to install all certs

Comment: the cert is already installed on my machine.